# Does the Ubuntu OS have a monitor driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I can't upgrade my current configuration
I have a Dell 7920 running Ubuntu 18.04.
I have a NVIDIA Quadro GV100, 32GB installed as CUDA 9.2
I am using this NVIDIA card to also drive my monitor.
During my original purchase the sales persons asked “Are you sure you don’t want a separate card for your monitor?” – I said No. I should have said Yes.
I can’t upgrade the Ubuntu OS to 19. or 20. or the NVIDIA card to 10. or 11. because the monitor is tied to the card.
I got a system upgrade that I allowed to start and it failed before completion so now I get an error on the CUDA.
I have a NVIDIA Geforce GT 1030 that I could dedicate to the monitor but will not work. It is using the same driver as the Quadro.
I would like to install a simple card that has the driver as part of the Ubuntu OS.
Does the Ubuntu OS have a monitor driver?
Is there a simple card I can buy that has an internal driver?
Is there a Non NVIDIA driver I can install that the Geforce GT 1030 would recognize?
Am I confused and not seeing the real issue?
Thank you and Peace,
Gerard

Comment: Need someone better to answer, but the sales person was trying to make more money( unless you are a highend gamer).  Monitors are not tied any graphics card( maybe Apple's new 5000$ monitors), you can unhook and hook up to any PC/OS.

Comment: Only NVIDIA cards can use the Gsync feature on compatible displays, which is an adaptive sync feature that slows down the display's refresh rate if your PC can't produce enough FPS to max out the display. In these conditions, the feature marginally reduces the screen tearing artifacts that can occur when the display and GPU are not perfectly synched. TBH you're not missing much and Gsync displays come at a premium

Comment: And you can definitely use a Gsync monitor without a Gsync compatible card.  You only miss out on this one feature which does not even make any difference except for in 3D gaming

Comment: Additionally... Trying to use more than one display adapter is a nightmare logistically for your window manager if the cards aren't identical and physically linked together. Sounds like you were being up sold in the worst kind of way

Comment: Don't really need a graphics card to run a monitor, most( not all) CPUs have graphic capability.  Depending on your needs, might be all some people need.

Comment: I am using the NVIDIA card for Convolutional Neural Network modeling only. The monitor is dark during the model run. I am using the monitor to start and stop the model, do some file management, and gather some data.

Comment: in response to crisp659. I have zero HDMI ports on the Dell 7920. So I need a card with an HDMI port. 
I have four HDMI ports on the NVIDIA card. I am using one. I would like to use None. I have one HDMI port on the Geforce GT 1030 but no driver other than NVIDIA.

Comment: I do not know enough, but this link might help some.  Your main problem seems to be updating nivada and cuda, maybe make new question.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/926946/ubuntu-cannot-install-cuda-and-nvidia-driver?rq=1